# angular-google-map-container flows off screen with Ionic and Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I'm building a SPA with Ionic and Angular. My map shows up just fine when it takes up the full screen (i.e., ion header + map only) but in one of my screens, I'm trying to show the ion header + a form + the map so that the map would only occupy ~50% (~325px) of the screen. My issue is that, for this screen, the map still takes on the full screen height (~625px) so that ~50% of the map exists off-screen.

My current structure looks as follows:

- ionic nav bar
- formContainer div (height determined by contents) wraps the form
- mapContainer div (height set to fill the rest of the visible screen via flex box) wraps the map

I think that my issue is caused by this css styling:

```
.angular-google-map {
  height: 100%;
}
.angular-google-map-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

My hypothesis is that the height gets set to 100% (~625px) before the mapContainer div can determine its height (~325px). Has anyone had any luck wrapping a map so that its height only takes up the visible div?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set top and left. Also remember that ionic adds a new scroll class to your content

```
.map-container .scroll{
    height: 100%;
}
.angular-google-map-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```